# Method parameters not used in its implementation

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in java (I have just study c++) and I have to read and understand a java code.

Ok so I've got a function

```
public void analysis(IStochObserver obs, IVector obsValues, IVector predictions,
    IStochModelInstance mainModel, ITime analysisTime) {
        .....................]
```

But in the implementaion (which is pretty long that's why I did not write it here), obsValues and prediction never appears!

Is there any reason ? It's a professional code so I don't think it's a mistake or something like this...

Comment: There doesn't appear to be enough information here to answer your question.

Comment: Looks like bad design.

Comment: Where did you get this? I'd say it was probably used in a previous revision

Comment: `It's a professional code so I don't think it's a mistake or something like this`. You've a long way to go if you never question "professional" code. There is a reason bugs exist every grade of software, **everyone** makes mistakes.

Comment: You'd be surprised how many products are prototypes with almost no changes made from prototype to production

Comment: It's a code from the software openda. Here the function documentation http://www.openda.org/docu/openda_2.1/doc/javadoc/algorithms/org/openda/algorithms/kalmanFilter/EnKF.html#analysis(IStochObserver, IVector, IVector, IStochModelInstance, ITime)

Comment: sorry here is the documentation http://bit.ly/1n4drKn

Comment: 1. In java there are no functions, only methods. 2. `unused` variables , professional code is full of those guys, it's not like an *un-professional* code where you just go ahead anch change some method signatures...

Comment: Is that class an implementation of an interface? Its fairly common for an interface to define method signatures which cater for a broader range of scenarios than some of the concrete implementations require.

Comment: There could be many reasons to try to explain why the method has this design. Only the authors of the code could give a proper explanation. Voting to close since it is primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be possible, that this method overrides a method from the baseclass. 
Then the signature of the method defines parameters, which are used by some implementations of the childclasses, but by others not.

Comment: Good thinking, although in that case it would be wise to wonder if that method even belongs in the base class. You'd end up passing `null` and then if you try to use one of these parameters later on, boom: `NullPointerException`.

Comment: ho yes you're right... there is an @Override just before the method

Comment: If you only use the Interface (or baseclass) from an outside view, then you don't know that the implementation doesn't use some parameters and so you won't pass `null`. I think it has to be defined in the documentation, whether it's allowed to pass `null`. If it's not allowed, the implemetations have to handle null-pointers.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the developers declared those parameters, but managed to implement what they wanted without using them all, then they forgot to remove them from the method signature.

There's nothing wrong with the code, it will compile. Wether it's bad design or not, that's another matter